# Cookiecutter template testing, what is cookies.bake?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I am Trying to figure out how to write a test suite for my cookiecutter template.

after looking at the tests for the cookiecutter-django template in `cookiecutter-django/tests/test_cookiecutter_generation.py` I see that most of the test functions take a parameter called `cookies`. Within the test functions themselves there is a method call on whatever object is being passed in as the cookies parameter that is called `bake`.

I would like to know what this object is and where it's imported from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `cookies` appears to be a [fixture](https://github.com/hackebrot/pytest-cookies/blob/master/README.rst#pytest-cookies) that is defined in `pytest-cookies`, as shown in the related [pytest_cookies.py source code](https://github.com/hackebrot/pytest-cookies/blob/master/pytest_cookies.py#L93).

The `cookies` fixture actually appears to be [a wrapper for cookiecutter](https://github.com/hackebrot/pytest-cookies/blob/master/README.rst#pytest-cookies) itself. Additionally, the related `cookies.bake()` method can be used to [generate a project](https://github.com/hackebrot/pytest-cookies/blob/master/README.rst#generate-a-new-project) based on your given `cookiecutter` template.

It may be interesting to note that `pytest-cookies` is a plugin for `pytest`, and as such, this plugin is accessible during testing as the related [`pytest` documentation indicates](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#installing-and-using-plugins):

> If a plugin is installed, pytest automatically finds and integrates
>   it, there is no need to activate it.

Thus, because the [requirements](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/requirements.txt) specify that `pytest-cookies` is to be used with `cookiecutter-django`, the `cookies` fixture from `pytest-cookies` should automatically be available during testing.

Comment: OK That clears it up! I did not realize that the pytest plugin automatically provided the fixture to the namespace. I was looking for a specific import.

Comment: @Pythonvtr250 I know what you mean about that!